# Java fatal error in native code, problematic frame: C [msvcrt.dll+0x8867a]

Tags: java, libgdx, lwjgl, msvcrt

I'm developing a small game with LibGdx (based on LWJGL). Tested the jar i built on two different PC's and everything worked fine. On a third one, however, the game crashes after a few seconds. Following error log is produced:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x73f9867a, pid=2016, tid=0x00000bc0
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcrt.dll+0x8867a]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Looks like something is wrong with msvcrt.dll, which is Microsoft Visual C++ Package, right?

Do you have any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: Other than ensuring that you're up-to-date with all the latest Java patches and possibly OS patches, I don't think there is much you can do (re-install?).

Comment: Did update Java. I'll try searching for OS updates. Thanks.

Comment: Need complete crash logs to identify the problem, atleast stacktrace and vm arguments?